# El Capitan Apache error message AH00526

Tags: macos, apache

Yesterday I upgraded my Mac from Mountain Lion to El Capitan. Trying to get apache2 working I get the following error message:

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 20 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf: Invalid command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.

What might be the remedy?

Comment: [Get localhost running on Mac OS X Yosemite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454160/get-localhost-running-on-mac-os-x-yosmite)

Comment: Did you look at line 20 of the file mentioned in the error message?

Answer (score 34):

[LockFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile) is one of the directives of Apache ≤ 2.2. This was replaced by [Mutex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex) in Apache 2.4, which is the version of Apache installed with OS X 10.11, El Capitan.

Edit the file `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf` to remove this part:

```
#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
  LockFile "/private/var/log/apache2/accept.lock"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Then check config `apachectl -t` and restart `sudo apachectl restart`.

Comment: This works. This happens when you update your MacOSX from your previous OSX version.

Answer (score 16):

I looked up the [information on the file http-mpm.conf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile) at the Apache website:

It says LockFile is a correct directive. I don't know why I'm getting the same error you are. So in terminal, I went to:

```
/etc/apache2/extra
```

and restored the `httpd-mpm.conf` file from before I loaded El Capitan. I used these commands:

```
sudo mv httpd-mpm.conf httpd-mpm.conf.elcapitan
sudo mv httpd-mpm.conf~orig httpd-mpm.conf
```

and entered the commands:

```
sudo apachectl restart
apachectl configtest
```

and got "Syntax OK"

If I enter http://localhost in my browser, I get the page "it works".

Comment: whats the important change from your original config file?  I am starting from fresh so I don't have known working config file.

Comment: I have the same issue, but this doesn't actually offer any fix.